# Is there any way to set the action to focus on the most recent updated date on tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Is there any way to set the action to focus on the most recent updated date? Every Time when tableau extract refreshes, the new date value will be added, and the default action will not update and always focus on the value that along with the published format.

According to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLy2v.png) the default action was set to 2012, therefore, the image below was reflecting the value of 2012. However, when the extract is updated, the bar graph will have one extra bar that represents 2013. How to let the cube image reflex the value from 2013?

Comment: Jason, what do you mean by focus?

Comment: Petr, sorry I should express more clearly. The focus means being selected. Since I have other graph and their value are depended on the action selection.